# PHP string manipulation on cookieid

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Currently on my webpage, im showing my users their cookieid, which has two parts associated to it, known as their `partyid` and `userid`,

the way it is set

> localhost/setcookie.php?ptyid=1&uid=628929

result

> 1%3A628929

the way it is shown

```
echo 'Cookie Set => 
PartyID : ' .substr($_COOKIE["cookieid"],-8,1). ', UserID : ' .substr($_COOKIE["cookieid"],2);
```

this was going fine till my **setcookie.php** only allowed the users to set `partyID` as 1 and `userID` had to have exactly 6 characters in it. but now i have to allow them to use any `partyid` and any amount of characters to the `userID`.

Therefore is there anyway I could use a substring(or any other method) dynamically to serve any `partyid` or `userid`. i think of something which could detect the `%3A` and split the string but I fail to find a way for that.

Comment: Why not use PHP sessions and set separate variables? Better still, your users wouldn't be able to manipulate the data like they can with a cookie

Comment: starting a session is a expensive operation which relatively slows down things... i am not intending to do anything with the cookie setting this is just a tricky problem of splitting the string correctly... and i cant force users to do what i want thats the problem... i have to accept whatever they enter and manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

When storing the cookie, concatenate the parts by a predefined separator (can be single or multiple characters). Then you can use `preg_split` to split the parts instead of `substr`.

This requires the parts them self must not contain the separator. You can make it a constraint for users. Or you can `base64_encode` the parts to make sure they will only contain certain characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try using a standard encoding instead. Something like `serialize` or `json_encode`. It would easily store your data in a string and let you pull it out into your script without the hassle of writing your own parser and hoping your delimiter is never entered.

```
$data = array('partyid' => urldecode($_GET['ptyid']), 'userid' => urldecode($_GET['uid']);
setcookie('cookieid', serialize($data));
```

Then you can do this

```
$data = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookieid']);
echo 'Cookie Set => PartyID : ' . $data['partyid'] . ', UserID : ' . $data['userid'];
```